# Is there a simple way to add a class to java.lang

Tags: classloader, java

Is there a simple way to add my own classes to java.lang (in the context of a desktop application, not applet/servlet). The idea is to get access to some methods that have been stupidly declared package private (such as Integer.getChars(...), and I don't want to copy all that code).

Simply declaring a class in the java.lang package triggers a SecurityException when my class loads.

I'm aware I could unzip the rt.jar and add my class there, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't require modifications to the installed JRE.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I want *direct* access to the methods, not roundabout detour access methods like reflection. the goal is to make a a call like Integer.getChars(int, index, chars) not only *compile* but also *execute* normally at runtime.

Comment: I honestly hope not :-) Now, seriously, if someone declared a method package private and not public, do you think it's a good idea to force your way to that method, knowing very well that the method could disappear in the next release or a release after that?

Comment: While they could disappeat, the methods I want to access wont very likely disappear any time soon. And I'm fully aware that I'm asking for trouble by messing with the JRE's non-public parts.

Comment: _"messing with the JRE's non-public parts"_ Sorry but I cracked at that one... Now, seriously, don't you think there is a reason to make them package private? Of course... you always have reflection... tough it is oftenly a bad idea. Great power, great responsibility.

Comment: Not sure, but adding anything inside rt.jar could infringe upon java licensing terms?

Comment: @Gamb  *"Now, seriously, don't you think there is a reason to make them package private?"*. Of course, they didn't want to have to *guarantee* the existance of these calls for all eternity for the sake of compatibility. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your hope has been shattered :) The possibility exists in form of -X non-standard parameters (And it existed since Java 1.2, as it turns out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to add classes to packages protected by the boot class-loader's SecurityManager by using the non-standard "-Xbootclasspath/p:" parameter (Oracle VM).
Classes added in this manner are "trusted", and since they are located *before* rt.jar in terms of search order, this can also be used to *replace* classes defined in the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [Java Reflections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

```
Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class;
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getChars", int.class, int.class, char[].class);
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(new Integer(1), 0, 0, new char[] {'1'});
// OR
//m.invoke(null , 0, 0, new char[] {'1'}); since getChars method is static and doesn't require an instance
```

Comment: You beat me to it for a few seconds :). Now, the method being static, the first parameter of `invoke` can be `null`.

Comment: My bad, should have written *call methods directly*. Using reflection defeats the purpose - avoiding overhead and possibly garbage creation. Its a good answer though.